# How to write sequelize log to a file, instead of console?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to write sequelize log to file instead of console. All sequelize logs are being written to console, which is default.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share some of your code... what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 11):

Check out `options.logging` in the [**docs**](http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/sequelize/index.html?highlight=logging). The default value is

```
options.logging = console.log
```

which means all logging is passed to `console.log()`. So simply change logging to a function that append messages to a log / text file. Example

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  logging: myLogFunc
}); 

var myLogFunc = function(msg) {
}
```

**winston** is a good nodejs package for managing logs -> **https://github.com/winstonjs/winston**

Comment: example https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7821#issuecomment-311700339
(use winston.createLogger instead of winston.Logger for version of winston> 3.0.0)

Answer (score 7):

This is the dirty way (use only in local environment):

```
import fs = require('fs');

const logStream = fs.createWriteStream('./sql.log', {'flags': 'a'});

const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  logging: msg => logStream.write(msg),
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite::memory:', {
  // Choose one of the logging options
  logging: console.log,                  // Default, displays the first parameter of the log function call
  logging: (...msg) => console.log(msg), // Displays all log function call parameters
  logging: false,                        // Disables logging
  logging: msg => logger.debug(msg),     // Use custom logger (e.g. Winston or Bunyan), displays the first parameter
  logging: logger.debug.bind(logger)     // Alternative way to use custom logger, displays all messages
});
```

use any of one logger i used winston

```
logging:  msg => logger.log('info',msg)
```

this worked for me